# How to ensure consistent margin space in css?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
        grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:orange;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:green;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    /*grid-template-columns: 1fr;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div style="width:600px; background-color:cyan;">One</div>
  </div>
   <div>Two</div>
</div>
```

When the screen width is large enough, it shows like this

[image]

Notice there is page margin, so theres space on the left and right side. But if I make the screen width smaller, the right side space disapears.

[image]

Notice, I have the page scrolled all the way to the right, but there is no right side margin space anymore.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks